# Kubuntu 15.04 on Dell XPS L322x - not detect external monitor over displayport

Tags: kubuntu, xps, displayport

As in the subject - XPS connected (minidp->dp) to additional LCD display but not working. System seems to not detect the display at all.

Comment: It's not solution, but some kind of workaround. I used minidp->dvi adapter then regular dvi cable to connect to the monitor and worked correctly.